# Installing Hiredis with pip on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, pip

I´ve been trying to install Hiredis in my virtual environment. I developing in windows 7.

At first i got the vcvarsall.bat error (or something like that). I read a lot of blogs and suggestions to this problem but i found no suitable answer. I tried "Windows GCC (MinGW) binaries for Python developers", I installed the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (ISO), etc. I suppose that the problem is because this packages contains C code.

My question is, after dealing with all this for over a week, does anyone have another useful idea on how to install Hiredis OR how to deal with the vcvarsall.bat error?

The help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this question still open?

Comment: I know it's been a while. I wanted this for a project and I couldn't find any wheel files. so i decided to build it myself. If anyone's looking for a wheel file for python 3.6 or 3.7 then you can download them [here](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/qde4wcpoa01te/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper (no officially supported) way to make this run under Windows. Even ActiveState Python does not offer a working hiredis package: https://code.activestate.com/pypm/hiredis/

For me the most important question is: why would you want to run hiredis under Windows? Developing a Redis client without using hiredis is just fine under Windows.

Do you plan using Windows Redis clients in production? Do you already know that their performance will not be good enough? If you can answer both of these questions with a clear "YES", then you need to proceed working on getting a proper hiredis build for Windows. If you are not so sure about either question, then this is premature optimization. Just work with the default parser.

Comment: I´m actualle following a tutorial, but i will get back with another question in the future. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Also, hiredis is required by aioredis library, even for development.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it could help you but I have compiled the .whl file for this on windows 10 64bit file
link [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oN794TmyWhai_k71NELAv1sZNiyq_5Rw/view?usp=sharing)

steps to install:

1. Go to folder where you've downloaded the .whl file
2. Press Shift + right click and the context menu will open
3. Click open powershell window here
4. When the powershell window opens enter this command

```
pip install .\hiredis-1.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```